# Конфигурация приложения из файла

Tags: java

Интересует настройка конфигурации java приложения из внешнего файла, файл  может лежать где угодно на компьютере пользователя, Вопрос в том ка его найти. Есть такой пример кода, но ему надо указать каталог примеренный.
'

```
static void searchForConfigurationFile(String path, String fileName) {
    boolean flag = false;
    File f = new File(path);
    //список файлов в текущей папке
    String[] list = f.list();
    //проверка на совпадение
    for (String file : list) {

        if (fileName.equals(file)) {
            flag=true;
            System.out.println(path + "\\" + file + " ");
            //если найден, то выход
            return;
        }
        if (!path.endsWith("\\")) {
            path += "\\";
        }
        File tempfile = new File(path + file);
        System.out.println(path + file);
        if (!file.equals(".") && !file.equals("..")) { // !!!
            //иначе проверяем, если это папка
            if (tempfile.isDirectory()) {
                //path += file;
                //то рекурсивный вызов этой функции
                searchForConfigurationFile(path + file, fileName);
                if(flag) return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Правильно либо держать конфиг файл рядом с самой программой, либо позволять пользователю указать путь до папки где он лежит. ТЧК. Шариться по системе пользователя - так себе затея и вызывает недоверие: с какого фига программа по системе моей лазит? Я бы сразу удалил программу

Answer (score 2):

У этой задачи есть такие решения

1. Хранить файл с настройками в месте, которое для этого предназначено в конкретной ОС. Этот каталог можно получить функцией `System.getProperty("user.home")`
2. Спросить у пользователя где он желает хранить настройки.
3. Если конфигурационный файл предназначен только для чтения, то хранить его можно в каталоге программы. А путь к нему получить вызовом

   ```java
   URI uri = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
   String path = getParentRealPath(uri);
   ```